# Theme Customizer - How to create a sub panel

Tags: themes, theme-customizer, sub-menu, settings-api, custom-write-panel

In Theme Customizer, i'd like to create a sub panel like this one of wordpress:
[image: Theme Customizer SubPanel]

When we add a new item, a new panel which allows us to pick up a item displays on the right, how can i do the same ?

Thank you !

Comment: Since you seem to be using redux framework, you'll be happy to hear it's natively integrated in it : https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/customizer-integration/

Answer (score 1):

This slide-out panel for picking a widget or nav menu item to add is specific to the implementations of Widgets and Nav Menus in the Customizer. There is no generic facility for adding this UI feature, so I suggest looking at Core to look at how it is implemented there to copy into your plugin. For nav menus, see the `AvailableMenuItemsPanelView` JS and the corresponding CSS:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/js/customize-nav-menus.js#L92
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/css/customize-nav-menus.css#L557

Comment: As someone who is also interested in an answer, I find this very lacking. It is one thing to say that it is impossible, but really very low quality and not very helpful to say "Read the Fucking Code" without even pointing to the relevant code.

Comment: Added links to the relevant code.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be using redux framework, you'll be happy to hear it's natively integrated in it :
https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/customizer-integration/